# Xcode - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7

i am using open and select data code in Today App Extension in my App i have got following issue in my App don't know how to fix it

[image]

Comment: Check framework is added properly, Note - Better to use FMDB instead of SQLite whole native code.

Answer (score 1):

Error got solved...i just need to import sqlite framework in link and library section in Today Extention section

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you add sqlite3 lib in Xcode, you need to select option to add it in main Target.[image: Add it to main target app]

Second step is to add "libsqlite3.0.tbd" in Link Binary with Libraries.

I think, if your follow these two steps, there will be no linking error.